# On-site symmetries can be gauged, but is a gaugeable symmetry necessarily on-site?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-anomalies, lattice-gauge-theory

I've always liked lattice QFT because it's mathematically unambiguous and non-perturbative, but it does have two drawbacks: (1) the lattice is artificial, and (2) some features are messy. One of those messy features is chiral symmetry. As an example, the lattice model of a free Dirac fermion in even-dimensional spacetime is easy to construct, but if we construct it in such a way that the non-chiral symmetry $\psi\to\exp(i\theta)\psi$ is on-site, as we usually do, then the Nielsen-Ninomiya theorem tells us that the chiral symmetry $\psi\to\exp(i\theta\Gamma)\psi$ cannot be on-site. (I'm using $\Gamma$ for the product of all the Dirac matrices.)

Instead of thinking of that messiness as a drawback, we can also think of it in a more positive way: it almost helps us understand why the chiral anomaly must exist. On-site symmetries can always be gauged, but we have no such guarantee for non-on-site symmetries. If that last part could be strengthened to "non-on-site symmetries cannot be gauged," then this really would help us understand why the chiral anomaly must exist.

**Question:** It is true that non-on-site symmetries *cannot* be gauged? In other words, is a gaugeable symmetry necessarily on-site in *every* lattice version of the theory?

I'm guessing that this is not true. I don't know why we'd ever want to use a lattice version in which a gaugeable symmetry group is realized as a non-on-site symmetry, because that would be unnecessarily messy,$^\dagger$ but is it actually *impossible*?

My question is similar to [another unanswered question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440799), but that one asks about ensuring the absence of anomalies, while I'm asking about ensuring the *presence* of an anomaly.

---

$^\dagger$ I say "unnecessarily" because I'm assuming that anomaly-free symmetries can always be on-site in *some* lattice version. I don't know if that's true, either. That probably-more-difficult question has [already been asked on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74500).

Also related: [When can a global symmetry be gauged?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61280)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are definitely not-on-site symmetries which can be gauged, but it's not obvious how to do it on the lattice.

For instance, a free fermion in 1+1d has a U(1) x U(1) symmetry (vector and axial, if you will), of which only one of the two U(1)s is on-site in any formulation. Either one can be gauged however (at least in the field theory), but not both simultaneously, because of the chiral anomaly.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me back to my senses! Now I see what I was missing: we can make either $U(1)$ on-site (but then not the other one), and we can gauge either one, but after gauging one of them, the other one is *no longer a symmetry at all*. On-site symmetries can be gauged, but non-symmetries cannot be gauged (of course). Still not obvious to me exactly how to gauge the non-on-site $U(1)$, but I should be able to work it out in this simple example. Thank you (+1)!

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I'd be quite interested if you figure out an answer to the puzzle of how to gauge the hidden U(1)! I thought about it a little bit before but it seems like it's *very* nonlocal. If we write the charge density in k-space as $\int dk \rho(k) a^\dagger(k) a(k)$, then $\rho(k)$ is a step function, leading to a $1/x$ non-locality of $\rho(x)$...

Comment: Djordje Radicevic has some interesting papers I think may be relevant to this question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.04906 https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01022

Comment: After thinking about this more, I'm not sure I follow the argument. Either one of the two $U(1)$ factors can be on-site (and the other one off-site) in a lattice formulation, and either one of the two $U(1)$ factors can be gauged, but those are two separate statements, so this doesn't seem to imply that the non-on-site factor can be gauged in any given lattice formulation. As far as I can see, it only implies that we can gauge either $U(1)$ factor by choosing a lattice formulation in which that factor is on-site. Am I missing a step in the argument?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly either U(1)s can be gauged in the field theory, but I don't know how to do it on the lattice.

Comment: Understood. I'm really just looking for something like an existence or non-existence "proof" (non-rigorous is okay), which doesn't necessarily require any example. I posted this belated comment because I re-read your answer today and was intrigued by the first line, which seems to suggest that "(non-)on-site" might have a meaning that's independent of any specific lattice formulation. Am I reading too much into that line?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Maybe I don't see what you're saying, but on-site or not seems to depend on the lattice formulation, no? It's certainly related to the anomaly in that an anomalous symmetry can't be on-site, but I'm not sure if all anomaly-free symmetries can be realized in an on-site way (like that other question was asking). Apparently the axial symmetry of a free fermion can be gauged in some sense, because I believe the field theory controls gaugeability, but the usual lattice formulation makes this very non-obvious.

Comment: Ok, I was just over-thinking that first sentence. It sounds like we're in sync: in any given lattice QFT, gauging a non-on-site symmetry may be difficult, but it's not known to be always impossible. I spent some more time playing with the $1+1$ dimensional free Dirac field, using a simple lattice version with an exact chiral $U(1)$ that is not on-site. I don't see how to gauge it, but I also don't see why it would be impossible, so I'm in limbo... Anyway, thank you for your patient replies!

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about this until now, but an example of a gauged non-on-site symmetry has allegedly been known since 1998! It was described by Lüscher in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9811032. It's allegedly a nonperturbative construction of a lattice chiral $U(1)$ gauge theory that works for any anomaly-free representation. It's not simple, but it looks accessible. Now I just need to find enough free time to really study it.